# Android: can't get 30 fps from camera

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2

I'm using ImageReader to get frames from phone's camera using Camera2 API.
I've set `RepeatingRequest` inside my `onConfigured` callback function and I logged `image.getTimestamp` inside `onImageAvialable` function for calculating the fps.
When I looked at the time stamps on logcat I saw that there are only 20 fps (20 time stamps per second).

My questions are:

1. Is my way of calculating fps is good? is there a better way?
2. If it is good, then why I'm getting 20 fps and not 30?

Here are relevant parts of the code:

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
        Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        Log.d(TAG, "onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE" + image.getTimestamp() );
        // If STOP CAPTURE button hasn't been pressed yet

        if ((!isStopped) && (image != null)) {

            // Get the current frame
            ByteBuffer pixelArray1 = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[pixelArray1.remaining()];
            pixelArray1.get(bytes);

            Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2, image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            mat.put(0, 0, bytes);
            Mat rgb = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

            // OpenCV function - convert from YUV which is the camera format into RGB which can be processed
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2BGR, 4);

            int pixelStride = image.getPlanes()[0].getPixelStride();
            int rowStride = image.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride();
            int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * 640;

            final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640 + rowPadding / pixelStride, 480, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Utils.matToBitmap(rgb, bitmap);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Update screen with new frame
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
            image.close();
        }
        else {
            closeCamera();
        }
    }
};
```

onConfigured:

```
public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured: BUILD REQUEST AND CAPTURE");
        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = cameraCaptureSession.getDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            requestBuilder.addTarget(imageReaderSurface);
            //cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(requestBuilder.build(), null, handler);
            cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(requestBuilder.build(), null, handler);
            Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured: AFTER CAPTURE");
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured: CANT CREATE CAPTURE REQUEST");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the logcat which shows 20 time stamps per second:

```
03-24 11:41:30.919 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi 

D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176055988501
03-24 11:41:30.964 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176106451209
03-24 11:41:31.014 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176156344543
03-24 11:41:31.067 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176205880116
03-24 11:41:31.120 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176256464074
03-24 11:41:31.168 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176306533293
03-24 11:41:31.217 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176357056886
03-24 11:41:31.269 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176406944855
03-24 11:41:31.313 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176457030845
03-24 11:41:31.363 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176506663397
03-24 11:41:31.414 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176556684438
03-24 11:41:31.467 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176607584803
03-24 11:41:31.520 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176658480428
03-24 11:41:31.567 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176706916105
03-24 11:41:31.613 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176757571834
03-24 11:41:31.664 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176807395636
03-24 11:41:31.717 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176857408865
03-24 11:41:31.767 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176907807199
03-24 11:41:31.816 16254-17780/com.example.noamm_000.talkwithcompviawifi D/CAMERA_IMAGE_READY:: onImageAvailable: IMAGE AVAILABLE39176957648657
```

*I tried putting in comment all of the work that being done in the `onImageAvialable` and leave only the time stamps logging but I still got 20 fps.

Thank you,
Noam

Comment: Frame rate can vary on some devices based on the lighting conditions (darker environment can mean lower frame rate). Try testing it in a bright environment.

Comment: @samgak I've tested it only in a bright environment, also, I'm missing more than 10 fps (50%) - could light have such a dramatic impact on fps?

Comment: @samgak I tried again and aimed the camera straight on a lamp and got 23 fps. Nice, what about the missing 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal.

Documentation for setRepeatingRequest clearly states that "With this method, the camera device will continually capture images using the settings in the provided CaptureRequest, **at the maximum rate possible**." Frame rate you will get depends on many things - capture request settings, camera hardware, available cpu power, images captured etc.

Comment: Ok, so I guess what I want to know is if there exist a way that I can force the frame rate to be 30 (or even higher)? or at least be constant as I need it to be static for later calculations.